# Hide/show div resetting after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

hope everything is going well. I'm working on a web application trying to implement some JavaScript code.

My web application is made up of three sections: each section has a title and a button which, if clicked, display a div tag that was not visible before. Pressing the same button again will hide that same div. Obviously, each button works for its related section; so pressing Section1 button will show/hide only the Section1 div, and so on for the other sections/buttons.

More precisely, to make mainpage.jsp easier to use, when I press the button to show for example Section1 div, the other two divs become non-visible: this means that only one div can be displayed at a time.

No problem so far, my function – `hideandshow(spoiler)` – works, but now I'm trying to implement two features.

The first feature is really important: my application needs to remember if it was displaying a div when I reload mainpage.jsp, to be able to display that same div after the refresh too, keeping other divs not visible. At the moment, the page resets all divs after reload.

After some searching I understood that localStorage, or sessionStorage, are the best ways to reach my goal, but after several tries I still can't make it work. Being new to JavaScript, I think I'm missing something important, so I hope you guys can help me find that out.

The second feature, less important because it's like an aesthetic style feature, is make each button able to change its name when pressed, switching between "Show Section (number)" (div not visible) and "Hide Section (number)" (div not visble) every time is clicked.
Unfortunately, I have no clue about how implementing this feature. I tried several codes I took from Stack Overflow but I wasn't able to implement them correctly. In fact, my buttons didn't change the name correctly at every click and the button name modify affected other buttons too, not only the three sections ones. This is why I didn't even try to keep that full-of-errors code.

I'm new to JavaScript and I really tried my best, running out of ideas. Thanks in advance for your time, patience and help.

My code:

```js
   // Checking localStorage  
    if ( (JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('activespoiler'))  !== 'none') && (JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('activespoiler'))  !== null) )
    {
        document.getElementById(localStorage.getItem('activespoiler')).style.display = 'block';
    }

    // Show/hide div content defined by id (spoiler1, spoiler2, spoiler3)
    function hideandshow(spoiler)
    {
        if(document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display === 'none')
        {
            document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display = 'block';
            localStorage.setItem('activespoiler',JSON.stringify(spoiler));
            
            // Closing other spoilers
            if (spoiler === 'spoiler1')
            {
                document.getElementById('spoiler2').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('spoiler3').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else if (spoiler === 'spoiler2')
            {
                document.getElementById('spoiler1').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('spoiler3').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else if (spoiler === 'spoiler3')
            {
                document.getElementById('spoiler1').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('spoiler2').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        else if (document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display === 'block')
        {
            document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display = 'none';
            localStorage.setItem('activespoiler','none');
        }        
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="hideandshow('spoiler1')">Show/Hide Section 1</button>
  
    <div id="spoiler1" style="display:none">
            This is the hidden text SECTION-1! <br>
            <form action="mainpage.jsp" method="POST">
                <button type="submit">RELOAD PAGE SECTION-1</button> 
        </form>
    </div> <br><br>
<!-- Section 2 -->
<button type="button" onclick="hideandshow('spoiler2')">Show/Hide Section 2</button>
  
    <div id="spoiler2" style="display:none">
        This is the hidden text SECTION-2!
        <form action="mainpage.jsp" method="POST">
            <button type="submit">RELOAD PAGE SECTION-2</button> 
        </form>
    </div> <br><br>
<!-- Section 3 -->
<button type="button" onclick="hideandshow('spoiler3')">Show/Hide Section 3</button>
  
    <div id="spoiler3" style="display:none">
        This is the hidden text SECTION-3!
        <form action="mainpage.jsp" method="POST">
            <button type="submit">RELOAD PAGE SECTION-3</button> 
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: inline onclick is sign of bad programming habit, use addEventListener instead. Also, JS should go right before the closing body tag (if not defered). Not in a render-blocking manner like you're using it.

Comment: Use Element.classList.toggle instead of assigning styles in JS. Avoid `style="display:none"`, use a class instead and toggle that class from JS.

Comment: PS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details then from JS use the `.open` on the other ones.

Comment: If you will need some help with using @RokoC.Buljan method - feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First feature:

You can check value when page loaded by this code:

```
// Checking localStorage
    window.onload = function() {
        var spoiler = localStorage.getItem('activespoiler');
        if(spoiler !== 'none'){
            document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById(spoiler + '_button').textContent = 'Hide Section ' + spoiler.slice(-1);
        }
    }
```

Second feature:

Not ideal, but working variant:

1. Add id to your buttons like `spoiler + _button`:

   ```
    id="spoiler3_button"
   ```
2. Change script with this code:

   ```
    // Checking localStorage
    window.onload = function() {
        var spoiler = localStorage.getItem('activespoiler');
        if(spoiler !== 'none'){
            document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById(spoiler + '_button').textContent = 'Hide Section ' + spoiler.slice(-1);
        }
    }

    // Show/hide div content defined by id (spoiler1, spoiler2, spoiler3)
    function hideandshow(spoiler)
    {
        var oldSpoiler = localStorage.getItem('activespoiler');

        if(oldSpoiler !== spoiler && oldSpoiler !== null) {
            document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById(oldSpoiler).style.display = 'none';

            document.getElementById(spoiler + '_button').textContent = 'Hide Section ' + spoiler.slice(-1);
            document.getElementById(oldSpoiler + '_button').textContent = 'Show Section ' + oldSpoiler.slice(-1);

            localStorage.setItem('activespoiler', spoiler);
        }
        else if (oldSpoiler !== null) {
            if (document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display === 'none') {
                document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById(spoiler + '_button').textContent = 'Hide Section ' + spoiler.slice(-1);
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById(spoiler + '_button').textContent = 'Show Section ' + spoiler.slice(-1);
            }

            localStorage.setItem('activespoiler', spoiler);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(spoiler).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById(spoiler + '_button').textContent = 'Hide Section ' + spoiler.slice(-1);
            localStorage.setItem('activespoiler', spoiler);
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

every thing is ok in your code except this line:

```
localStorage.setItem('activespoiler',JSON.stringify(spoiler));
```

delete **JSON.stringify** and just use **sploiler** to prevent add **""** to your tag id, like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('activespoiler',spoiler);
```

and it will work!

it is also better to not use **inline-style** here on your html tags :

```
style="display:none"
```

and you can use javascript codes to hide them in initial rendering at the top of your scripts, like this:

```
document.getElementById('spoiler1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('spoiler2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('spoiler3').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: I think you can add optional chaining in JS codes part like `document.getElementById('spoiler1')?.style?.display` to prevent possible errors if the element is not found or not yet rendered